# Image with parameter - HTML

Tags: html

I do not know how to frame the question. And I do not know how the below tag is working...

```
<img src="img.png?value=23"/>
```

This tag is working fine. And its rendering the image correctly.
Does the `value=23` has some effect??? or It is been ignored by Browser??

I do not even know how to Google this!!! Is it like passing parameter to the Image??? If that is the case, how to retrieve the value attribute. Does the parameter has any sense

Comment: Most likely it doesn't do anything, but you can always try removing it and see if anything changes. The only possible solution I could think would be that the number can be changed when the image changes to make sure the client doesn't use a cached version.

Comment: ok! But my question is does it make any sense?? or it is simply igored  by browser?? bcoz!! HTML is the most lenient language!!! where everything works for no reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample i don't know what does it mean 
But it's possible to write

```
<img src="path_img.png?<?php time() ?>" />
```

to force your browser to download resource without using cache

Answer (score 6):

It depends on server, if you have png MIME type as text and you parse the files as if they were text files with php code then it has effect.

It really depends on configuration of server not a browser.

Morover, **mod_rewrite** can be used to change files that look like png to php files.

Adding parsing png files via php parser
       `AddType application/x-httpd-php .png`

**mod_rewrite**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)\.png$ img.php?value=$1
```

With these line`asdfasdf.png` will be treated as `img.php?value=asdfasdf`

So in this case when you use `$_GET['value']` on `asdfasdf.png` or `img.php?value=asdfasdf`. It will have effect.

If server is not configured to do such things and images are images(Yes i know it's briliant sentence) then it has no effect on common image.

To sum up.

**It depends on server configuration not on the browser**

Answer (score 2):

If this image is dynamic in some way, then the server that's hosting this image must be generating the image from PHP code.

Take a look at the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), which lets you use PHP to generate images based on nothing or other images. The parameter must be passed to include that value inside the image (for example, an image that includes the text "123" or calculates using it somehow, for example a user ID).

Then an `.htaccess` on the server rewrites the extension of `.png` to `.php` (or maybe another one) to make it look like a genuine image to some libraries and crawlers, or scripts etc.

Another option, is that this is a simple image and that `value` is being ignored, or is just random to make sure the image isn't cached.

Answer (score 2):

The `value=23` only has an effect if the server uses it. The browser requests `http://example.com/img.png?valud=23`, so the server will see the parameter.

For example, with PHP, if your use `$_GET['value']`, and that variable changes what image is sent, then the `value=23` is needed.

Parameters are often sent with images to specify a height or width, or to determine which image is loaded.

Comment: ok.. As mentioned @Travesty.. If the value is a random number , or any random parameter, will "specially signal" the browser understand it its a new image and avoid caching??

Comment: @madhairsilence As far as the browser is concerned, it doesn't matter if you're requesting `img23.png` or `img.png?value=23`: the browser assumes it's a different file whether it really is or not, so it doesn't load from cache, unless `imp.png?value=23` was already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It sure does!

For example, take a look at this piece of software that is intended to dynamically resize an image.

http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

If done correctly, adding parameters to an image url could be very useful.

**Edit:**

As others point out, you need to ensure that the server knows how to handle the extra parameter. In this case it is intended to resize/watermark/rotate an image. It can certainly do other wonderful things.

Comment: That depends on the server hosting the image - if it is generated dynamically or not. You make it sound like it can be assumed that this logic applies everywhere.

Comment: Ok! Just want to confirm!! So . the browser does not even know what the parameter. It simply renders the image consider ? as some parameter! And it has notthing to do with clear Caching!!!

Comment: It doesn't *clear* the cache, but if the parameter keeps changing then the image "name" keeps changing, and it's considered a new image and therefore not previously cached by the browser. And yes, the browser itself doesn't care about that parameter, but the server might use it to retrieve different content

Answer (score 0):

`value=23` is not ignored by your browser but by the server.

It's like passing parameters to the web server. For images it will be mostly ignored.

Comment: Saying it is ignored by the server is wrong. It depends on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The **arguments** in a url are mostly used for getting some information about a specific item but can be used in more other ways. When talking about the images, the browser won't ignore the argument `value=23` but the server you are using will.

But if the image is some sort of dynamic then it may be used in order to change the image's URL or other things.